# Encoding error when decompressed Gziped text

Tags: c#, gzip, compression

Having an issue with this code i try to decoded it.
Characters such as ", {, }, false, and integer value objects are all wrong decoded with char of  and � characters

```
 string myString = "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";


        byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(myString);
        Console.WriteLine("" + System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompress(data)));
```

The decompress funtion

```
public static byte[] decompress(byte[] compressed)
    {
        using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(compressed))
        using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            gzipStream.CopyTo(outStream);
            return outStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The code i try to decoded is an html code i scraped it

Comment: It is really helpful to investigate issue if you provide thing how to compress data and then make it into base64.

Comment: As @dotnetstep suggested, could you edit your question to tell us how you obtained the value for `myString`? I think that something might have gone wrong at the encoding stage.